# php mysql display/get all the products ordered by the customer grouped by ORDER_DATE from 2 tables using join

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have these two tables `CART` and `ORDERS`. I would like  to display/get all the products ordered by the customer grouped by `ORDER_DATE` how can I do this by Joining these two table? or what is the correct code, script or syntax for it.. This is a 1:n relation I also want to display the items ordered by the customer ORDERED BY order_date..

`CART` Table:

- cart_id
- product_id
- user_id
- prod_name
- price
- quantity
- image

`ORDER` Table:

- order_id
- cart_id
- user_id
- total
- customer_name
- order_date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juan, this i getting really long and i'm not sure whether the Stack Overflow site is intended for this kind of dialog, but i'll try to explain once again. I will simplify your tables so the code i post here is simple.

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    orderID int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    user int unsigned not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (orderID)
);

CREATE TABLE orderitems (
    oiID int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    order int unsigned not null,
    item int unsigned not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (oiID)
);
```

The above is assuming that there is a table of users (Where is the user's name and email etc) and table of items (where the item names and item prices are).

I'm also assuming (wrongly, but for the sake of simplicity), that in my scenario noone will ever have the desire to buy more than 1 piece of any item i'm selling and noone will ever want to buy more than 3 items at the same time.

Then my HTML entry form will be simple enough, because the user must be logged in when ordering (Thus i already know their userID - and it is held in my php $_SESSION['userID'] global variable), the order is always dynamically assigned at the time when user clicks CHECKOUT button (submits the form) and so the only thing we need the user to ENTER is the item ID (or rather pick it from a drop down list for example).

so here is VERY SIMPLE entry form:

```
<form action='orderit.php' method='post'>
    <select name='item[]'>
        <option value='' selected='selected'>Pick an item from the list!</option>
        <option value='1'>Knife</option>
        <option value='2'>Spoon</option>
        <option value='3'>Lava lamp</option>
        <option value='4'>HB pencil</option>
    </select><br/>
    <select name='item[]'>
        <option value='' selected='selected'>Pick an item from the list!</option>
        <option value='1'>Knife</option>
        <option value='2'>Spoon</option>
        <option value='3'>Lava lamp</option>
        <option value='4'>HB pencil</option>
    </select><br/>
    <select name='item[]'>
        <option value='' selected='selected'>Pick an item from the list!</option>
        <option value='1'>Knife</option>
        <option value='2'>Spoon</option>
        <option value='3'>Lava lamp</option>
        <option value='4'>HB pencil</option>
    </select><br/><br/>
    <input type='submit' value=' Checkout ' name='do'/>
</form>
```

From the above you see than when when user clicks checkout all the data (namely the choices the customer made are sent to the `action` which is set to `orderit.php`. Please note that i am not bothered about making sure the user is submiting valid information and i'm not using the latest technology (that being msqli) instead i'm using the deprecated mysql routines.

So here it follows:

```
<?php
     //here you will have your database opened, session initiated and so on
     // $db contains the database connection handler
     // $_POST['userID'] contains valid user's id

     if (isset($_POST['item']) && count($_POST['item'])>0) {
         //they ordered something we can create the order
         $q=mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders SET user='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['userID'])."'",$db);
         if (!$q)
             die("An error while creating new order");
         $orderID=mysql_insert_id($db); //fetch the just-now created order's ID
         foreach($_POST['item'] as $item) { //go through all the ordered items
            $q=mysql_query("INSERT INTO orderitems SET order='$orderID', item='".abs((int) $item)."'");
            if (!$q)
                die("Couldn't save item $item of order #$orderID");
         }
         print "Your order was saved successfuly!";
     } else
         die("This is an empty order");
?>
```

And that's all.

Please note that i am writing this code from top of my head now, so there may be typos or other types of error. take it more as an approximate guide rather than as a working piece of code.

Answer (score 4):

in case you are looking to list all the items **ordered** by order date (not grouped) then it would be like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `order` 
LEFT JOIN cart ON cart.cart_id=`order`.cart_id 
ORDER BY order_date ASC
```

or :

```
SELECT * 
FROM cart 
LEFT JOIN `order` ON `order`.cart_id=cart.cart_id
ORDER BY order_date ASC
```

as from the structure it seems that cart can contain several orders (while order can not contain more carts) - that's where you must tell us, whether it is 1:n relation (of those two tables) or whether it's 1:1 (in which case you do not need the cart_id and can use the order_id instead as the linking element in both tables)

in case you want to "group" it somewhat, then you will have to sacrifice the detail (which is to be grouped together) grouping is useful, if you wanted to see the total values of all the orders - but doing so, you would only see the total value but NOT the items from each order (not in a line by line view)

**EDIT:**
*[ sorry i forgot.. it's a 1:n relation.. i also need to display the ordered items from each customer.. is that possible ? :) ]*

in that case the structure does not seem very sound assuming the master table is the "order" then the table with detail should contain refference to the master table:

CART Table:

- cart_id
- order_id <sup>(added)</sup>
- product_id
- user_id
- prod_name
- price
- quantity
- image

ORDER Table:

- order_id
- <strike>cart_id</strike> <sup>(removed)</sup>
- user_id
- total
- customer_name
- order_date

Again your question isn't very clear. Do you want to see the items a user purchased grouped by the items (that is, if they buy a pencil today rubber tomorrow and another pencil the day after tomorrow, you will see two lines of result similar to:

```
item   | qty
-------+----
pencil | 2  
rubber | 1
```

then use:

```
SELECT `order`.*, product_id, product_name, SUM(quantity) AS qty 
FROM `order` 
LEFT JOIN cart ON cart.order_id=`order`.order_id
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY product_name
```

Comment: sorry i forgot.. it's a 1:n relation.. i also need to display the ordered items from each customer.. is that possible ? :)

Comment: @JuanTamad answered above, for any further re-fining queries, can you start a chat or, be more precise and i will answer it in another "answer" below this one (so that we do not bloat this comment part here) :)

Comment: i`m sorry i`m just a newbie here.. it`s somehow like that.. so here is the flow the customer can view his orders and when he clicks order-details.. that's where he can see all the items/products he ordered on that specific order(order_id or date), 

orders->view_details->list of products he ordered on that date

im sorry i`m not very good at explaining..

Comment: i was confused because because i didnt have the right reference from the cart table to the order table except for user_id.. thaankss again :) that's why i have to use joins..

Comment: @JuanTamad No problem Juan :) Glad to be able to help.

Comment: can u repost your last post.. the one with the queries i`m trying something i thought that might be useful.. :)

Comment: @JuanTamad those were only simple selects from each of the table. I was saying there, that you would first list the orders of that user, then when the user clicks a specific order you would refer to another php script (or another branch of the same php script) and print out the detail of the specific order_id which would be send to that script for example through $_GET array. the queries were the likes of: **SELECT * FROM \`order\` WHERE user_id='$userId' ORDER BY order_date DESC** (sorted so the latest orders are on top) **make sure to mysql_real_escape_string()** all the variables!

Comment: one more thing, how do i populate the order_id in the cart table ? sorry i have to ask this stupid question :)

Comment: @JuanTamad you have to populate that at the time when you create your order (that is when you are saving it) 1) you save the details to the table \`order\` and have the order_id generated by auto_increment (i'm guessing) then by using $orderId=mysql_insert_id($order_insert_query) you will get that auto-generated order_id and use it in your **INSERT INTO cart SET order_id='$orderId', product_id='$something', ...**  Obviously you will have to use the proper variable names that you are using in your script...

Comment: So i have to insert the ordered items in the cart table while adding the orders at the same time?

Comment: @JuanTamad It's answered below.